# PDFBox can't create Form if fields contain non-latin character

Tags: coldfusion, pdfbox, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to create PDF from ColdFusion10 using Apache PDFBox lib.
I have a template PDF file with form fields and filling them out with user data.
But if user inputs non-latin character in any form field I got exception.
For example: Turkish language has character 'İ' (capital i with dot) so I got message:

*U+0131 is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding.*

Form fıelds in the pdf template use 'Arial' font. Should I use any specific font embed to PDF template to make all characters work? Or it depends on what fonts installed on server (Linux)?

Any help very appreciated!

Comment: Please **A** share the template PDF which you fill in and **B** tell which version of PDFBox you use.

Comment: The code in my answer in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3832 may partially help... i.e. by embedding a font in a different way. And yes we need the PDF. If it is confidential, find some government pdf that exhibits the same problem.